# Allowing Users to Log in Drupal 7 Has an Issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have my fresh Drupal 7 web site up and running.  I am currently testing it.  My first test is to try the functionality of creating a new user.  I tested added myself (no, not my admin account -- a different one with a different email address).  The new user's (mine) email got an alert saying that the account would be approved by the admin and further instructions and password would be sent to me.

I got the alert email also at the admin email address and I logged on and assigned the account a password and approved the account.

But the new user's email never got the notification.  I also tried to find the user's email address by using the admin's privileges on the site in case I needed to deliver the message to the user by hand.  But I could not find out how to do that.

Please help and advise.

---

Update:

I think this has to do with the fact that the admin email is a gmail account. Is there an issue with this?

Can I change the admin email after the installation?

Comment: Check you mail configuration on your server (and your local if your are in dev mode), try to use mail function into php file to check if you'll receive it. Check spam filter into gmail too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.  The problem was that one has to look in the "spam" folder to see email that is sent by automated means.  Both email addresses, the Admin's as well as the test user account, had emails being sent directly to the spam folder.  I think I managed to fix the problem on the Admin gmail account.  Once I get a new user, I will simply have to inform the new user to check his spam folder for directions.

Comment: The [smtp module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) can help prevent your email from being flagged as spam using gmail (or an email from google apps for business)